# Trying to add 10 values to sql database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This is easy enough task under sql management studio. I clicked on edit top 200 rows. And entered first set of values as:

Everything should be same except Index and rollnumber

```
Index class rollnumber age 
1      A      1         10
2      A      2         10
3      A      3         10
...
10     A      10        10
```

Problem i am having is:
I copied first row and pasted in second row and when i try to change it in sql editor i am unable to. 
Can anyone please tell me what is the best way to do this through sql editor?

Or if there is easier way to do SQL insert in this case?

Comment: What are you finding hard about SQL inserts?

Comment: @RedFilter - What is the best way to do a insert in above scenario? Should i do manul insert? If i do manual is there a way to copy first row and paste it to second and then change Index and Rollnumber? Or is there better way to do this with sql insert statement?

Comment: I can think of no circumstance where I qwould allow anyone to use the GUI to enter or adjust records. If records need to be adjusted for an application (such as a lookup table) then they should be scripted and in source control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make sql queries and execute it in editor.

```
insert into table values( 1, A, 1, 10);
insert into table values( 2, A, 2, 10);
insert into table values( 3, A, 3, 10);
insert into table values( 4, A, 4, 10);
insert into table values( 5, A, 5, 10);
insert into table values( 6, A, 6, 10);
insert into table values( 7, A, 7, 10);
insert into table values( 8, A, 8, 10);
insert into table values( 9, A, 9, 10);
insert into table values( 10, A, 10, 10);
```

Comment: And with SQL Server **2008** and onwards, you can even simplify it - just `INSERT INTO dbo.Table VALUES(...), (.....), (.....), (.....)` - no need to always repeat the `insert into....` - just define multiple tuples of data to insert

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy it without the Index field if you have it as primary key.

Comment: i have not set any primary key on the table. How can i do that now? Do i have to set a primary key first?

Comment: Some editing application complain if you want to paste in a row that contains the primary key that already exists in that table. So sometimes you paste in all other columns and the index is auto assigned. I don't know if that is your case but it's worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the Index is an IDENTITY column. The database will assign the value

There may be gaps: this is the nature of IDENTITY colums

In this case, learning to use the raw SQL INSERT will help: you have far more control over what you do. [SET IDENTITY_INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx) will allow you to override the identity property

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as a quick SQL Statement (assuming your first column is an IDENTITY column):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTableName(class,rollnumber,age)
VALUES ('A', 10, 10),
       ('A', 11, 10),
       ('A', 12, 10)
```

This format is easy to copy and paste individual values into until you have all f them accounted for, then can be run once to put them in (or saved and rerun in other environments).

If the index column is not an IDENTITY column but is instead just a UNIQUE column that it is giving you an error on, you can specify it as a column and provide additional unique values like so:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTableName(index, class,rollnumber,age)
VALUES (10, 'A', 10, 10),
       (11, 'A', 11, 10),
       (12, 'A', 12, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Index column is a primary key with Identity, you could use the following to create N - 1 rows:

```
DECLARE @Counter int;
SET @Counter = 0;

WHILE (@Counter < 10)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table ([class],[rollnumber],[age]) VALUES ('A',@@IDENTITY + 1,10)
SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
END
```

This also assumes that rollnumber must be equal to your index.